# npm package with classes not compatible between typescript and transpiled versions

Tags: typescript, oop, tsc, transpiler

Hi I'm coding an npm package, is coded in typescript and transpiled.

That package is now been used in a typescript app, but I have 1 error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'import("/home/chriss/Sites/ORM/connection").DB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/chriss/Sites/ORM/dist/connection").DB'.
Property 'connections' is protected but type 'DB' is not a class derived from 'DB'.
```

Is the same Class just 1 is the typescript one and the other one is the transpiled one

I declare like this:

```
import { DB } from "@unicoderns/orm/connection"
...
constructor(config: Config, baseURL: string) {
    this.config = config;
    this.db = new DB({ dev: config.dev, connection: config.dbconnection });
}
```

And then call the model like this:

```
this.usersTable = new users.Users(jsloth.db);
```

where jsloth.db is the this.db from the first code.

And this is *in the npm package* whats expecting:

```
constructor(DB: DB, privacy?: string);
```

What can I do?

**EDIT 1:**

Package already released, source available at:

https://github.com/unicoderns/ORM

The dirty and quick workaround was add `| any` to the type expected
`model.ts` at line 56
`constructor(DB: DB | any`

This should be corrected :)

The library consuming this package is also OpenSource and the code can be found at:

https://github.com/unicoderns/JSloth

Once you remove the `| any` from the package several files should "yell" the error in the IDE but probably still works, like `source/system/apps/auth/endpoint/v1/index` at lines 57 and 58

Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Somehow you are importing both `/home/chriss/Sites/ORM/connection` and `/home/chriss/Sites/ORM/dist/connection` in the app.  Pick one.  If you add more of your code and your `tsconfig.json` file to the question, I can help you figure out how the problem arose.

Comment: Thank you so much @MattMcCutchen, I edited the question to include the requested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you point the `"main"` and `"typings"` fields in `package.json` of the `@unicoderns/orm` package to the `dist` subdirectory, then an import of `@unicoderns/orm` will go to that subdirectory.  When you import a non-main module of `@unicoderns/orm`, such as on `source/system/lib/core.ts` line 25:

```
import { DB } from "@unicoderns/orm/connection"
```

you need to use the path in `dist` to maintain consistency:

```
import { DB } from "@unicoderns/orm/dist/connection"
```

See [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8305) and particularly [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8305#issuecomment-343004602) for more information.

Comment: Oh you are good, it makes sense, thank you so much for your time @MattMcCutchen, however, `"@unicoderns/orm/dist/connection"` seems unnatural to me, there's any workaround I can do to keep it like it is? (`"@unicoderns/orm/connection"`), any configuration I can chage, structure? I don't know.

Comment: Your main options are described in the issue I linked: either change the `@unicoderns/orm` package so the `.js` and `.d.ts` files are generated alongside the `.ts` files, or set the `paths` compiler option on every project that uses `@unicoderns/orm` to map `@unicoderns/orm/foo` to `@unicoderns/orm/dist/foo`.